# Reading External JSON file - NodeJs

Tags: node.js, json

I'm trying to read an external JSON file in NodeJS, but its returning `undefined` at the start of the JSON. I'm using `readFileSync` since this is a config file, and this process needs to be completed first before moving on.

NOTE: There is NO white space at the top of the external file.

EXTERNAL JSON FILE

```
{
   email:{
       username: "someUserName",
       password: "somePassword"
   },
   database: {
      username: "databaseUser",
      password:"datbasePassword"
   }
}
```

NODE JS

```
"use strict";

const fs = require("fs");
let rawData = fs.readFileSync("/run/secrets/secrets_file.json");
let secrets= JSON.parse(rawData);

console.log("SECRETS: ", secrets);
```

RETURNS

```
undefined:1
data = {

SyntaxError: Unexpected token d in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

What's happening here?

Comment: Validate your JSON. It's invalid. You need to double-quote the keys as well as the values.

Comment: Thanks @jarmod - I'm too use to writing objects, not JSON. Thank you.

Comment: Most modern programming editors with lint highlight the issues which is a good way to detect them.

Comment: also note that if you need to read the file only one you can just use the `require` way of loading a JSON file. Subsequent calls to the same require will return from cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON file is not valid JSON. You need to quote the keys.

```
{
    "email": {
        "username": "someUserName",
        "password": "somePassword"
    },
    "database": {
       "username": "databaseUser",
       "password": "datbasePassword"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you check And key "d" in json which is not visible in the front of screen. that may written by mistake some where else in the file